# Update ListView.builder itemCount after the data is refreshed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So I have a FutureBuilder that calls different methods depending on what button is pressed.

```
child: FutureBuilder(
 future: buffetPressed
   ? API().getPackages(widget.restaurant.id)
   : API().getFoodItems(widget.restaurant.id),
```

Which returns a Listview.Builder

```
return ListView.builder(
 scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
 shrinkWrap: true,
 itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
```

The problem is snapshot.data.length is different for each method as each api call returns different data. Everything else updates in the list (names, etc) but the length does not update causing RangeError (index): Invalid value: not in inclusive range. Which I understand is from the itemCount being wrong. Is there a way to update the itemcount when the button is pressed? I'm fairly new and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Shouldn't the `snapshot.data` is the output of `API().getPackages` or `API().getFoodItems` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe snapshot.data changes based on a button press. By default it's packages but on press it changes to food. Then can be changed back by another press.

Comment: Then it should not be a problem because `snapshot.data` are depends on the output of the two.

Comment: The only problem is that itemCount: snapshot.data.length is not updating. Everything else is fine.

Comment: It is updating, otherwise you wouldn't get `Invalid value: not in inclusive range` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching from FutureBuilder to StreamBuilder.